# Trying to get my program to read a file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to get my code to read text inputs and compare it to text in "userInfo.txt" file.
I think i got it to do that; however, it does not output the results of the comparison.

Please check my code below:

```
String line = "";
String data = "";
boolean result = false;

BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("userInfo.txt"));
try{
  while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null)
    data += "\n" + line;
  inFile.close();
}  catch(Exception x){};

String [] allData = {data}; // saving the txt inside allData

System.out.println("Enter UserName: ");
 String userName = kb.nextLine(); 

System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
 String pass = kb.nextLine();

try{
  //read user name and password then compairing it to the user and pass insde the file
  for(int i = 0; i < allData.length - 1; i++)
  {// checking userName

    if(allData[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userName))
      result = true;
    else
      System.out.println(result +" Wrong userName");

    // checking password

    if(allData[i + 1].equals(pass))
      System.out.println("Welcome " + userName);
    else
      System.out.println( result +" Wrong password");
  }
} catch (Exception x){};
```

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you got in with the username and password, but I don't see the code that actually compares the 2 files, you have all the text stored in data, correct? I only see you comparing it to the username and password. Speaking of which, what are these text files going to contain? I ask because that for loop comparing allData[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userName) scares me

Comment: It looks like your input file has two lines. First line has the username and second line has the password. Is that true?

Comment: What output do you get and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: show us part of your userInfo.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your array `allData` only contains 1 String, which is the whole content of your txt file.

Change

```
String [] allData = {data};
```

to

```
String [] allData = data.Split("\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is created on this line:

```
String [] allData = {data};
```

In that line, you create an array with a single element that has the entire text of the file.

Instead, consider doing something like this:

```
List<String> allData = new ArrayList<String>();
try{
  while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
    allData.append(line);
  }
}  catch(Exception x){}
finally { 
  inFile.close(); 
}
```

then you can use allData.get(i) to get the line you're looking for.

By the way, a couple of notes by the way of code review:

1. ALWAYS use {} for `if`, `while`, etc. It makes it easier to read and also is less likely that you'll make a mistake later about whether something will get executed as part of the block or not.
2. Don't swallow exceptions (`catch(Exception e) {}`). It will make it harder to debug, because you won't know if you've made a mistake or had bad input.
3. `inFile.close()` belongs in the `finally` block. That's because you want to close your file handle even if you get an exception that causes you to break out of the try block.